# Salesforce Visualforce CSS Fixed div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, salesforce, visualforce

I am building a custom analytics page and replicating the UI of the native Action Bar in Salesforce1. The intention is to keep the Action Bar fixed at the bottom of the screen. It seems to be working great in Android and browser mobile emulator but not in iOS app.

CSS

```
 #dashboard-utility-banner{
   border-top:1px solid #999;
   background-color:#eeeeee;
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0px;
   height:74px;
 }

 #dashboard-utility-banner .utility-tools{
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 11px;
 }
```

Bootstrap HTML

```
<div id="dashboard-utility-banner" class=" col-md-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class = "col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 customTextFontClass utility-tools" >
    <a href="#" onClick="createNote();return false;">
      <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon_container--circle slds-icon-standard-performance">
        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon--small">
            <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS0102,'assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#note')}"></use>
        </svg>
    </span><br/><span class="">Create Note</span>
    </a>
  </div>       
  <div class = "col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 customTextFontClass  utility-tools" >
    <a href="#" onClick="showPriceList();return false;">
        <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon_container--circle slds-icon-standard-topic">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon--small">
                <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS0102,'assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#cases')}"></use>
            </svg>
        </span><br/><span class="">Price List</span>
    </a>    
  </div>   
  <div class = "col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 customTextFontClass  utility-tools" >
    <a href="/apex/displaySiteAccounts?accountNumber={!accountNumber}&id={!accountID}">
        <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon_container--circle slds-icon-standard-account">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon--small">
                 <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS0102,'assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#company')}"></use>
               </svg>
     </span><br/><span class="">Locations</span>
    </a>
  </div>       
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to reproduce your problem. Even you have not specified what your problem exactly is. Using your source local show me 2 issues.

First you have not provided any sizes to your svg element. So using some example svg files (include them direct to the source!), will be displayed by a size, I see only the transparent top left edge. I have to set the size then. Then it work fine.

The second problem you have, is using `<use xlink:href="myicon.svg"></use>` The external resource way doesn't work in any version (up to 11 tested) of Internet Explorer and safari. You you need to polyfill this. You can use this polyfill [jonathantneal/svg4everybody](https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody) for that.

Comment: I added some more details regarding the action bar. In regards to browser compatibility the page will only be viewed via iOS. Also, the svg sizes are from Salesforce Lightning experience CSS library. (Notice the classes on the container). https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/icons/